# Anylogic Dynamic Arrival Function doesn't work (agent and time dependent function)

Tags: java, anylogic

I have two types of arrivals, planned and unplanned, which is shown as agent's parameter.
I also have arrival shares for months, day of the week and hours of the day added as DB to the model, which is connected to the model using table functions "months()", "dayp()", "dayu()", "hourp()" and "houru()" (months shares are the same for planned and unplanned patients so I use on month DB for both).

In the source block, for each hours in the simulation I need to calculate the inter-arrival time considering patient type and time of arrival as presented in the picture. [image]

The table functions for planned patient types are here:
[image: month of the year share in the yearly arrivals]

[image: Day of the week share in the weekly arrivals]

[image: Hour of the day share in the daily arrivals]

This one does not give me any arrivals and basically gives me zero.
If I make a function that needs patients type as the argument (to decide whether use planned DBs or unplanned ones) and put it in the source Inter-arrival time formula, the model does not run and gives me the errors.

Can you please help me?
Appreciated in advance.

Comment: What errors? Have you tried to use `traceln()` to find out what your functions return? Best find out the root cause of the issue and report on that, tbh :)

Comment: I solved the errors issue. The problem now is that the getDayOfWeek() will stop updating after a week and getHourOfDay() starts with 0 - which can be reasonable - but remains 0 through the simulation. So, the model always only gives one arrivals and then no new agents arrive, due to the fact that the interarrival time now is equal to infinity...

Comment: Please always open new issues for new problems. SOF does not work like a forum, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Also, please share how you solved it, helps others in the future with similar problems ;)